# How to change the Date format as DD-MM-YYYY in salesforce lightning data table?

Tags: datatables, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

How to change the Date format as DD-MM-YYYY in lightning data table ?

The Result is 1936-06-12

I Want the result as 12-06-1936

Please help....

code snippet

{label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text',sortable:true},
{label: 'Birthdate', fieldName: 'Birthdate', type: 'Date',sortable: true,typeAttributes{day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric'}},
{label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email',sortable:true}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "type" attribute is case-sensitive, as are most things in Lightning. "Date" is an unrecognized value, so it defaults to text, while "date" is a recognized value that formats a value as a date. When reading any documentation regarding Lightning, assume that whatever is in the documentation is a case-sensitive value and must be precisely the right case or you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

See "Displaying Date and Time Using Type Attributes" on this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

I think you'll want to change your type attributes to this:

```
typeAttributes:{
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric"
}
```